# How to split aggregated variance of one random variable into multiple random variables?

Tags: variance, standard-deviation, random-variable, aggregation, disaggregation

I apologize if this question is trivial, but I didn't come to a conclusion by myself.

I have an aggregated forecast for a group of $n$ items, normally distributed with mean and standard deviation.  $(\mu_F, \sigma_F) $ **From this bulk forecast I am trying to go backwards to single item forecasts.**

From historical data I know, that the means of the $n$ items follow a known distribution. I can also assume independence. For simplicity let's imagin $n=3$:

We know that $\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3=\mu_F$ and $\sqrt(\sigma_1^2+\sigma_2^2+\sigma_3^2)=\sigma_F$

We also know the means follow the following distribution:

$\mu_1 = 0.2\mu_F ,$

$\mu_2=0.5\mu_F,$

$\mu_3=0.3\mu_F$

From the given information above, is it possible to assume $\sigma_1 = \sqrt(0.2)\sigma_F,    \sigma_2 = \sqrt(0.5)\sigma_F,    \sigma_3 = \sqrt(0.3)\sigma_F$ ?

If no, what assumptions have to be made? Is there a term for splitting the variance according to the weights of the means? Are there other methods to apply instead? I am grateful for any help or further resources. Does anyone know any academic papers, where something like this is applied?

**edit:**
Maybe it helps to give some more context. I am forecasting shoe sales. I therefore do my forecasting on an aggregated set of data. I combine all sizes of the same model. After I get my results I thought I could split the mean and the standard deviation back to the size level. I want to do this according to the average size distribution for the specific category of shoes.

Answer (score 1):

> From the given information above, is it possible to assume $$\sigma_1
> = \sqrt{0.2\sigma_F},    \sigma_2 = \sqrt{0.5\sigma_F},    \sigma_3 = \sqrt{0.3\sigma_F}$$

No, not at all. There's no reason the variance should partition in the same way the mean does. In a normal distribution, the two are totally separate from each other.